# Why that query isn't working as i expected ?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 3 AS x, 5 as y, (x+y) as z
```

The result what i expect;

```
x  y  z
3  5  8
```

The result what i get;

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'x' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SELECT clause (and column aliases) are evaluated at the same time and in no particular order. That is, at the same point you want z, the columns x and y do not exist yet.

```
SELECT
   (x+y) as z
FROM
    (
    SELECT 3 AS x, 5 as y
    ) t;
```

Comment: i'm gonna accept your answer because you have answered the reason why it is not working with an example thanks a ton! I wish to know lot more about the logic behind how mysql works :)

Comment: @motto: Thanks. This is SQL works generally (set based, declarative) not just MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

You can't refer to a column alias that way. Try

```
SELECT (tmp.x + tmp.y) as z FROM (SELECT 3 AS x, 5 as y) tmp
```

Ref.: [Subqueries in the FROM Clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @x:=3 as x, @y:=5 as y, (@x + @y) as z;
```

Comment: Wow you've got my upvote on that very nice and different approach with using variables, i'm watching your answers and profile very closely may be i can get more from you :)

Answer (score 0):

because you can't use your alias X newly created as part of the selector. Use your constant instead since you don't need the alias or a temporary table like other answers.

If your real problem is different please post it, maybe you are simply thinking this wrong

```
SELECT 3 AS x, 5 as y, (3+5) as z
```

Comment: yeah sry i forgot the 2nd alias.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to do this?

Since your query uses constants, this works fine.

```
SELECT 3 as x,5 as y,(3+5) as z;
```

Comment: my question is a simplified version of the real problem, your answer doesn't help too much.

Comment: It is difficult to understand the real question if you don't provide the context!

Answer (score 0):

it's possible that `z` is defined by query engine before `x` and `y`. that means `z` exists before `x` and `y`. and hence the error.

Comment: @Azodious after taking a look into the link you' gave i'm not sure how this is relevant with my question. are you sure this is a bug ? it's more likely a feature to me.

Comment: MySQL complains about `Unknown column 'x'`, that is 'x' is unknown within `(x + y)` expression, because there is nothing table-like to get `x` column from. The bug you referenced is about strange behaviour within stored procedures.