# MS SQL - is there a quick way to refer to the result of a case statement without re-doing the case statement?

Tags: sql-server

...In other words...

If I have a case statement that does this...

```
Case
when Type = 'payment' then net *-1
else net
end as 'pos_neg'
```

How can I use the result of that in another case statement that split payments and receipts by > or < that 0.

What I want to do is this....

```
Case
when 'pos_neg' >0 then 'pos_neg'
else 0 end as 'Receipts'
```

....and the opposite for payments.

the only way I know to acheive this is to nest the first case in the second....which is a lot of repetition.

Answer (score 0):

You could select from a nested select statement.

```
select case when 'pos_neg' > 0 then 'pos_neg' else 0 end as 'Receipts'
from
  (Select case when Type = 'payment' then net*-1 else net end as 'pos_neg'
  From Table) T
```

or use a Common Table Expression

```
with T(pos_neg) as (
  Select case when Type = 'payment' then net*-1 else net end as pos_neg
  From Table)
select case when pos_neg > 0 then pos_neg else 0 end as Receipts
from T
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he's asking for.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: well, it isn't possible to do it at the same level. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8878331/27535 for example in MySQL too.

Comment: Well I didn't downvote it for that very reason, but I think the answer should at least tell the asker that what they wish to do will not work.

Comment: You'll have to forgive me for my rudimentary knowledge of SQL. - is there a way to declare a variable somehow that is the result of the case statement?

Comment: @gbn: It is possible to do it at the same level if you use a CROSS APPLY (MSSQL only). Then you can take a value from one expression and use it in the next.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  case 
    when Type = 'payment' and net * -1 > 0
        then 'pos_neg'
    when Type = 'payment' and net * -1 <= 0
        then ...
    ...
    else 0 end as [Receipts]
```